# Can't hide keyboard in MvxFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-softkeyboard

I am developing **Xamarin Android Application**.I am using edit text in **MvxFragment** but when I type something in **EditText** and then go to another fragment ,keyboard is still open and can't be **closed or hidden** untill I press return key on keyboard.So how can I able to close or hide that keyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call something like this when closing your fragment:

public void HideSoftKeyboard()
        {
            InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            manager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);
        }

Add this to your activity, and call it from the fragment.